# Proving that no 2-state DFA decides the language A = {x ∈ {0, 1}* | bnum(x) is divisible by 3}

Tags: finite-automata

I am doing a problem where I need to prove that no 2-state DFA decides the language
A = {x ∈ {0, 1}*| bnum(x) is divisible by 3}.

It's seems pretty obvious at first, because aren't there only 4 DFA's with two states that define it? Also, since x is divisible by 3, the DFA would need to have 3 states to define the remainder values.

So I feel like I have a good understanding of the problem, but how do I more formally prove the statement? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Remainder values is indeed the clue! Obviously the strings $1$ and $10$ cannot end in a final state as they represent number `1` and `2` respectively. But can they end in the same state?

Comment: Arent 1 and 10 both remained of 1, so they both go in the R1 state. and 2, 11 would be in the R2 state. Right?

Comment: Are you reading the bits in binary numbers in the same direction as I do? I was assuming 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, etc.